# TFS issue export to Excel

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS for our Project Management, and I have some KPI charts in Excel that use imported data from TFS. I've noticed that tasks or user stories in the state 'Closed'or 'Resolved' are not imported. Nevertheless, my query in TFS gives those tasks/US as a result. What am I missing?

Regards,
Jan

Comment: How did you export the query result? Could you please provide the steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my side, everything works as expected.

The tasks or user stories in the state '`Closed`'or '`Resolved`' can be exported to excel successfully with the query.

Please double check to make sure that you have included the tasks or user stories with the the state '`Closed`'or '`Resolved`' in your query, and the query is saved.

[image]